# SQLAlchemy core insert does not insert data into db

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have such issue that SQLAlchemy Core does not insert rows when I'm trying to insert data using `connection.execute(table.insert(), list_of_rows)`. I construct connection object without any additional parameters, it means `connection = engine.connect()` and engine only with one additional parameter `engine = create_engine(uri, echo=True)`.
Except that I can't find data in db also I can't find "INSERT" statement in logs of my app.

May be important that this issue I'm reproducing during py.test tests.

DB that I use is mssql in docker container.

EDIT1:
rowcount of proxyresult is always -1 regardless if I use transaction or no and if I changed insert to `connection.execute(table.insert().execution_options(autocommit=True), list_of_rows).rowcount`

EDIT2:
I rewrote this code and now it works. I don't see any major difference.

Answer (score 1):

What's the inserted row count after `connection.execute`:

proxy = connection.execute(table.insert(), list_of_rows)
   print(proxy.rowcount)

if `rowcount` is positive integer, it proves it indeed writes the data into DB, but may be only present in a transaction, if so you could then check whether autocommit is on: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit

Comment: rowcount is always -1 regardless if I use transaction or no and if I changed insert to `connection.execute(table.insert().execution_options(autocommit=True), list_of_rows).rowcount`